# How to fix the back button light on Samsung Note 3

Tags: hardware, buttons

My note 3 back button light doesn't  light up. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The light is broken. This is a hardware problem, so we can't fix it for you.

You need to take it to your local phone repair shop, or return it to Samsung if it's still under warranty, and get them to replace the broken part.